# Blender exporting sharp edges to mesh file

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

Is there a way to export blender file to any of the mesh file format with sharp edge information? In other words, is there a mesh file format which supports sharp edge information in Blender?

Comment: It might really help us to understand what software you are expecting to export to ... 3dsmax, maya ... etc. Usually I would just used the "edge spilt" modifier and apply it before exporting, if I really need those sharp edges to showup in other software packages.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to:

1. Go to properties panel
2. Add edge split modifier and apply it.
3. Export your model to any format that behaves well with the target software.

[image]

Use edge split before exporting your file.

Comment: Which format you are talking about? What about .obj file?

Comment: @Abdul Kadir I think you misunderstood my sentence. What I meant was any format that behaves well with the target software you are exporting to. You have to test that yourself since you never did say what software you are exporting to ... eg. 3d studio max, Maya, Softimage, Autocad 3d ... so I wouldn't know how to advice what is the best format. Once you apply Edge split the sharp edges will appear in any format you export to. since what it does is to separate the model joined faces at the sharp edges you define in blender.

Comment: So even if you apply smooth shading on the model in other 3d packages the affected faces will never be recognised as one whole but 2 different elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to export your mesh while keeping the sharp edges these are the steps you will need to take:

### EXPORTING

- In Blender you need to make sure that your 'Sharp Edges* aren't actually *Creases*.
- In the event that they are *Creases* then go into *Edit Mode* (with the desired object selected).
- Select 1 of the creased edges and go to the top left and click *Select > Select Similar > Crease*.
- This should have selected all the 'similarly' creased edges (if not then you can manually do it, or find another way to select em all.
- Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>E</kbd> > *Mark Sharp*
- Once we now know all desired edges are sharp, go into your modifiers tab, add an '*Edge Split*' modifier. (I know nobody really uses this modifier so bare with me).
- Then you want to deselected *Edge Angle* and *Keep Selected* *Sharp Edges* (This basically says "Yeah I wanna split the edges that I have marked sharp" and forget the rest)
- Now you can apply the modifier and begin with your exporting. (*File > Export* whatever format you want)
- Then you can send it to someone or do what you want with the file, throw it in the trash a few time I don't care

### Importing

- This part is also annoying so bear with me, import the file into blender
- Then you may not notice it at first but if you put a subdivision surface modifier on the object you'll see pretty easily where the edges are.
- You will see all the edges you HAD marked sharp are now split, wow, you are doing great, keep it up.
- So from here, you want to *select one of the (cyan/blue) sharp edges* and go to the top left and click *Select > Select Similar > Sharpness*
- With these all selected you now want to click  <kbd>M</kbd> > *By Distance*
- Then you will see you have the edges joined now but they aren't sharp anymore (thanks blender) to fix this you should have everything still selected, if not then click *Select > Select Similar > Sharpness* and all the desired edges should be selected again
- Then you want to press <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>E</kbd> > press  <kbd>1</kbd>, this should mark everything as creased again and the edges should be nice and pointy, just how you like em

Pretty sure you can mess around from here on in.